# How to give weight to the specific field?

Tags: java, search, indexing, gwt, solr

I am using Apache Solr for indexing and searching. I have to give weight to the specific field so that If I make search then search has to perform on that field which is most weighted and then on others.

I am using SolrJ, Java, and GWT for development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To boost at index time you need to supply a boost statement in your update doc.

```
<add overwrite="true">
    <doc boost="2.0">
        <field name="id">1234</field>
        <field name="type">type1</type>
    </doc>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">2345</field>
        <field name="type" boost="0.5">type2</type>
    </doc>
</add>
```

The above example demonstrates how to boost a complete document (elevation) as well as how to boost a specific field.

For more documentation look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#index-time_boosts) and [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#line-40)

Answer (score 1):

Using the dismax (or edismax) query handler, you can set the qf (Query Fields) parameter to assign boosts to different fields. It uses this format:

field1^boost_val field2^boost_val....etc.

There are other good parameters to help you control your result ranking as well.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax

Comment: This does not answer the question about boosting at index time. You are describing a boost at query time.

Comment: If I want boosting at index time then I have to give boost value while  adding fields in document isn't it?
if yes then I do not need to give "field^2" at query time...Is it correct?